# Port forwarding web server port 80 - external traffic fails or directed to router page

Tags: iis, networking, iis-7, hosting

I have IIS running and on my internal network it functions correctly. When trying to access it externally (either with direct IP or dyndns hostname) I always get redirected to my router log in page.

I've set up an IP on the host machine (192.168.1.29) and forwarded port 80 on my router. Also I have set an in bound rule to allow port 80 in Windows firewall.

When the router firewall is in default mode I cannot access my machine externally "Webpage not available"
Disabling the firewall gives me a HTTPS security certificate warning and when accepted directs to the router login page.

Any suggestions?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your router is running its management pages on port 80. See if it has an option to change the port number for those pages.